# WPF DragDropEffects not set properly in Drop event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to drag-and-drop some data within my application. I want the DragDropEffects to be `Move` if the control key is NOT pressed, and `Copy` if the control key is pressed. It seems like this should be trivial, but I've searched a bunch and haven't found an answer to this.

Here is my code, based loosely on [Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static void dragSource_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(currentDragDef.DragSource, currentDragDef.Data, DragDropEffects.All);
    e.Handled = true;
}

private static void dropTarget_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    bool ctrlKey = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl);
    if ((e.Effects & DragDropEffects.Move) == DragDropEffects.None || ctrlKey)
    {
        // Control key is pressed or move is not allowed. Do copy/link.
        e.Effects &= ~DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    else
    {
        // Control key not pressed. Do move.
        e.Effects &= (DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Scroll);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

`e.Effects` is getting set fine in `dropTarget_DragOver`. The mouse cursor adds a '+' icon whenever I press control. However, in the `Drop` event, `e.Effects` equals `DragDropEffects.All` again. Why is this? How to I get `e.Effects` to equal something different in the `Drop` event? Or is this even possible?

```
private static void dropTarget_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Effects == DragDropEffects.None || !e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        return;
    var effects = e.Effects;
    // effects == DragDropEffects.All, but I want it to have the Move or Copy flag removed
}
```

Aside: another thing is that I'm using `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` instead of `e.KeyStates` because `e.KeyStates` seems to always equal `DragDropKeyStates.LeftMouseButton`. The `DragDropKeyStates.ControlKey` bit is always 0, even if control is pressed. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should duplicate the logic in your DragOver function in the Drop function, to determine the effects again.

Instead of reading the effects field from DragEventArgs, you should write it back. The value is passed back to the source and is the return value from the function DoDragDrop.

This is more or less described by Microsoft in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, but the behaviour is not obvious. I made the same mistake as you.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Thanks, I have fixed it.